# How to remove duplicate values from nested C# list

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-sql, nested-lists

I have a model setup like below:

```
public class ReportScheduleModel
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public List<ReportTimes> reportTimes { get; set; }
}

public class ReportTimes
{
    public byte hourOfDay { get; set; }
    public byte minuteOfDay { get; set; }
    public string reportType { get; set; }
}
```

I can then pass an entire list back to my controller with the following list format:

```
List<ReportScheduleModel> ReportSchedule
    [0]->Day: 'Sunday'
         [ReportTimes]: [0]->hourOfDay: '09'
                        minuteOfDay: '23'
                        reportType: 'Test1'
                   [1]->hourOfDay: '08'
                        minuteOfDay: '11'
                        reportType: 'Test2'
    [1]->Day: 'Sunday'
         [ReportTimes]: [0]->hourOfDay: '09'
                        minuteOfDay: '23'
                        reportType: 'Test1'
                        [1]->hourOfDay: '11'
                        minuteOfDay: '30'
                        reportType: 'Test1'
    [2]->Day: 'Monday'
         [ReportTimes]: [0]->hourOfDay: '09'
                        minuteOfDay: '23'
                        reportType: 'Test1'
```

In the list above you notice that `ReportSchedule[0]` and `ReportSchedule[1]` both have the exact same reporting times listed of "09:23 Test1".  What I'm trying to do is get to a list that does not have these duplicate values, it only keeps one of the duplicate reporting time values.  Therefore, my ideal filtered list based on the above would be: (It doesn't matter that `Day` is not grouped/unique, just the `ReportTimes` based on the same 'Day')

```
    [0]->Day: 'Sunday'
             [ReportTimes]: [0]->hourOfDay: '09'
                            minuteOfDay: '23'
                            reportType: 'Test1'
                       [1]->hourOfDay: '08'
                            minuteOfDay: '11'
                            reportType: 'Test2'
        [1]->Day: 'Sunday'
             [ReportTimes]: [0]->hourOfDay: '11'
                            minuteOfDay: '30'
                            reportType: 'Test1'
        [2]->Day: 'Monday'
             [ReportTimes]: [0]->hourOfDay: '09'
                            minuteOfDay: '23'
                            reportType: 'Test1'
```

Comment: I would suggest using [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT** Make sure that your **ReportTimes** class implements GetHashCode and Equals in a sensible way: i.e. the same entry always hashes to the same value, and different time entries hash to different values.

Then you can create a HashSet data structure for each day and linearly traverse your nested lists adding all report times from all lists into the appropriate set by day.

The above will ensure that only unique ReportTimes instances are kept for each day. And it will have linear-time performance in the number of ReportTimes instances!

Of course, you could also re-use the hash set and just do one day at a time..

```
var sets  = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<ReportTimes>>();

// assuming ReportSchedule is the list of ReportScheduleModel items
foreach(var scheduleItem in ReportSchedule)
{
     if(!sets.ContainsKey(scheduleItem.Day))
        sets.Add(scheduleItem.Day, new HashSet<ReportTimes>());

     foreach(var rt in scheduleItem.reportTimes)
     {
          sets[scheduleItem.Day].Add(rt);
     }
}

// at this point, each set in the sets dictionary will contain only unique items
// if you wanted to get all the unique report times for Sunday you would use something like:
foreach(var rt in sets["Sunday"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} - {2}", rt.hourOfDay, rt.minuteOfDay, rt.reportType);
}
```

I hope the example above is clear enough. And as I said in the beginning, please make sure to implement GetHashCode and Equals in the ReportTime class. Here's an example:

```
public class ReportTimes
{
    public byte hourOfDay { get; set; }
    public byte minuteOfDay { get; set; }
    public string reportType { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {            
        return reportType.GetHashCode ^ (hourOfDay << 8) ^ (minuteOfDay);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if(other is ReportTimes)
        {
            var ort = (ReportTimes)other;

            // returns true if the 'other' object represents the same time & type
            return    ort.hourOfDay.Equals(hourOfDay);
                   && ort.minuteOfDay.Equals(minuteOfDay);
                   && ort.reportType.Equals(reportType);
        }

        return false;  // if comparing to a non-ReportTimes object always return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used a hashset before, would a quick example from the info I gave above be possible or a link that is similar to my data.

Comment: see edits; please make sure to read about hashsets! You can't effectively use it unless you develop an understanding for what it does and why it's useful

Comment: Hashsets resemble Dictionaries where no distinction is made between key and value. They behave much like mathematical sets. Adding an item several times adds it only once, without producing an error.